# Flutter : RenderPadding object was given an infinite size during layout

Tags: flutter, dart, radar-chart

I was trying to have another widget in my flutter page so I get this error because of RadarChart.light :

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderPadding object was given an infinite size during layout.
The relevant error-causing widget was
Padding
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

how I can solve this problem

**Code**

```
SafeArea(
 child: Scaffold(
   body: AppBackground(
    child: SingleChildScrollView(              
     child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 9.0),
      child: Column(
          // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const HeadWidget(title: "Computer Science"),
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                RadarChart.light(
                  ticks: ticks,
                  features: features,
                  data: data,
                ),
                Text(
                  "PERFORMANCE BY COURSE",
                  style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                      color: Kwhite, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                ),
                const PerformanceByCourseCard(),
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 20,
                ),
                Text(
                  "PERFORMANCE SUMMARY",
                  style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                      color: KRedOrange, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                ),
                const PerformanceSummaryCards(),
                Text(
                  "PERFORMANCE BY PLO",
                  style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                      color: KRedOrange, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                ),
                const PerformanceByPLOCard(),
                Text(
                  "PERFORMANCE BY GA",
                  style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                      color: KRedOrange, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                ),
                const PerformanceByGACard(),
              ],
            ),
            RoundedButton(
              text: "DOWNLOAD YOUR TRANSCRIPT",
              press: (context) {},
              fontSize: 12,
              margin: 0,
              paddingHorizontal: 0,
              paddingVertical: 0,
              borderRadius: 5,
            ),
          ]),
    )))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Can't place Column widget inside column, It Means A parent of unbounded height can't hold a child which is given unbounded height.
Also at top level where you place singleChildScrollView, don't use it or wrap your Columns with fixed height sizedBox. It will solve your problem.